# Laravel Eloquent ignores orWhere query after WhereIn

Tags: laravel, eloquent

my Query:

```
return parent::whereIn('user_id', $users)->orWhere("user_id", $user->id)->get();
```

It only runs the first whereIn query and ignores orWhere query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this:

```
return parent::where("user_id", $user->id)->orWhereIn('user_id', $users)->get();
```

Comment: @Cem Flav: If my answer work for you then please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this??

```
   parent::whereIn('user_id', $users)->where(function ($query) {
      $query->orWhere("user_id", $user->id);
   })->get();
```